# Why is the output in the last row "Wuff Ringding" ? and not "Ringding Ringding"?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Hey guys can you help me wih my code. Its about polymorphism. I have just a question about the last row of the main function. Where is the output there "Wuff Ringding" and not "Ringding Ringding" ?

```
public class Hund{
public Hund (){
}
public String belllen(){
return "Wuff";
}
public String spielen(Hund h){
return "Wuff" + h.bellen();
}
}

public class Fuchs extends Hund{
public Fuchs (){
}
public String bellen(){
return "Ringding";
}
public String spielen(Fuchs f){
return "Ringding" + f.bellen();
}
}

public class Park {
public static void main (Strin[] args){
Hund bello = new Hund();
Fuchs foxi = new Fuchs();
Hund hybrid = new Fuchs();

System.out.println(hybrid.spielen(foxi));// Output is Wuff Ringding
System.out.println(foxi.spielen(hybrid)); // Output is Wuff Ringding
}}
```

Comment: Please ensure that you have a correct [mcve] first. Your first belllen method has 3 l letters. Your input does not even compile. For the actual question: start adding the @Override annotation when overriding methods. That should give you a first idea where your assumptions are wrong...

Comment: Please indent your code. Readable code is more likely to get read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has dynamic method dispatch, but it is only a single dispatch based on the runtime type of the object whose method you are invoking. There is no dynamic dispatch based on the runtime types of the arguments, instead the method (if there are multiple overloaded methods to choose from) is selected at compile-time based on the declared types.

> foxi.spielen(hybrid)

`foxi` is known to be a `Fuchs`. You have the following overloaded methods

- public String spielen(Hund h);  (inherited from Hund)
- public String spielen(Fuchs f); (declared on Fuchs)

`hybrid` is declared to be a `Hund`, so the first method will be called. It does not matter that it is actually a `Fuchs` at runtime. You'd get to the second method with `foxi.spielen((Fuchs)hybrid)`.

Maybe you intended to *override* instead of *overloading* the method? Then it would indeed have printed your expected result. But that did not happen, because to override a method, you have to match the parameter types exactly. If you intend to override a method, you should use the annotation `@Override` which will alert you have such mistakes.